# What is this process?

Tags: windows-7, process

The following process seems to be running all the time:

```
C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHCreateLocalServerRunDll {995C996E-D918-4a8c-A302-45719A6F4EA7} -Embedding
```

Anyone know what it is?

Scanned with MalwareBytes and Kaspersky Internet Security 2011

Using Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits.

Comment: rundll32.exe is a standard Windows/MS program to initialize a DLL. shell32.dll is a standard Windows/MS extension. The interesting part is the SHCreateLocalServerRunDll. Google doesn't shed any light on that. Does Registry Editor find anything in your registry for the hex argument at the end?

Comment: @Nathan did not find anything of interest when looking for "995C996E-D918-4a8c-A302-45719A6F4EA7"

Comment: Why are you suspicious of this legit Windows system file?

Comment: @Moab because I can't seem to find the source of why this is running... I've never had this process before and I haven't installed anything in the meantime.

Comment: Try Process Explorer, a powerful tool if you know how to use it..http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: You can also use PE to enable boot logging, maybe this will show what is loading it...http://www.msigeek.com/6231/how-to-enable-system-boot-time-logging-using-process-monitor-tool

Comment: @Moab Process Explorer didn't help, it was the first thing I looked for. The process seems to be owned by svchost.exe

Comment: I guess its a mystery, post back if you solve it.

Comment: @Moab I most certainly will... It real bad practice of leaving a question unsolved if you've solved it yourself...

Comment: After googling, I cannot find anything negative about "shell32.dll,SHCreateLocalServerRunDll" Have you scanned for nasties?

Comment: Reading back my own comments and questions, I can only cringe. I am so sorry everyone 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a Microsoft Windows [DistributedCOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_Component_Object_Model) server. It is safe as far as I can tell. I have seen it on other systems that were couple of weeks old and didn't get chance to get infected :).

Comment: @digitxp - According to Wiki it's a long deprecated technology, why would this still be on my Win7 64 bits computer?

Comment: I guess backwards compatibility with .net frameworks

Comment: Microsoft always uses long deprecated technology! You must be a Linux/Unix user.

Comment: @Moab Well mainly yes xD Is it that obvious huh?

Comment: @BloodPhilia, yes you seem to be Bright, logical, polite and a bit pragmatic, none of which works well when solving problems in Windows..  ;-)

Comment: @Moab Haha, well I'll consider that a compliment sir... And what brilliant deduction abilities! Chapeau!

Comment: @BloodPhilia, how did you know I am a Sir, now you are scaring me with your 6th sense!

Comment: @Moab And I think the Linux Badge might've given me away as well ;) Ah well, a Sir you behave good Sir!

Comment: Badge?, I don't look at that stuff, actually was a logical conclusion after reading many of your posts.

Comment: @Moab Read many of my post have you? I'll consider you my first fan! ;D

Comment: @Bloodphilia, its hard not to, you are all over this place!

Comment: @Moab hope that isn't a bad thing! :D

Comment: Its all good...

Comment: @Moab Good good! :D As a matter of fact, I do come across your name more often and often! Keep up the good work!

Comment: @Bloophilia, interesting one here....http://superuser.com/questions/224112/virus-malware-explorer-window-with-strange-user-logged-into-hotmail/228615#228615

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question. But the correct answer can be found here:
http://www.sevenforums.com/performance-maintenance/218109-rundll32-exe-running-all-time.html

> That GUID maps to the "Shell Hardware Mixed Content Handler", which is a COM handler that needs to run as "Interactive User", meaning run in a logged-on user's session (that's you ). The reason it needs to run in the context of a logged-on user is that it's actually the Autorun handler (enabling Autorun on my own Win7 box causes the same process to be spawned).
>
> If you don't want to see it, go into the control panel and disable Autorun. Otherwise, it needs to run for Autorun to work properly.

answered there by cluberti on 07 Mar 2012